# Finding the generating pattern in an integer sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I got a problem to find the generating pattern of the following integer sequence:

$$1,3,8,20,48,126,...$$

This page helped me in finding the pattern: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C8%2C20%2C48&language=english&go=Search

What I am interested in is, how to find the generating pattern of an arbitrary infinite integer sequence on my own? The sequence can be monotonous or alternating. Is there a way instead of guessing it?

By any means, correct me if I am using wrong terminology, English is not the language that my math professors teach on.

Comment: Your OEIS link actually gave you $13$ different sequences. And that is one problem with arbitrary sequences.  Another is that there are more infinite sequences of integers than there are finite ways of describing them

Comment: If the sequence is $s_n = a n^3 + b n^2 + c n + d $ for integers (or rational numbers) $a,b,c,d,$ the numbers $a,b,c,d$ can be found quickly using the calculus of finite differences.

Comment: part 2: if the sequence is from a linear recurrence, such as the Fibonacci numbers, that may be found using the "number wall" method in Conway and Guy, The Book of Numbers.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for your swift reply! Can you please explain to me what do you mean by "Calculus of finite differences"? Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @Shocky2 you can find a similar question here, including answers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998900/how-to-identify-the-pattern-of-a-sequence